# Buildfire: Editing Custom Apps

Tags: buildfire

We had a developer create an app with custom modules [calculator] and need some assistance in editing two.

The calculations being made are to determine the quantity of material needed for a certain job given the project size. One of the edits that need to be made is to have the app determine if the job is smaller or bigger than the two sizes of material that we use in order to provide the correct amount.

The other app that needs to be edited is text based but since the app is a custom module I am not sure how to access it.

Please advise at your earliest convenience.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hello Jorge, this seems like a very specific problem with your app. I'm not sure discussing this publicly would be the correct path. Have you reached out to the developer to see if he can send you the source code? Do you have access to the developer account that the custom plugin was submitted under?

Comment: Hi @Daniel_Madain - just saw your message. We currently do not have a developer handling our account and dont have access to the custom plugin. I have another edit to be made on another custom plugin so how should we proceed? Your internal Customer Success Manager was the one who directed me to this page to send in my request.